# Why is _ViewStart in MVC involved when controller returns an image file (non-view result type)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using ASP.NET 4.6 MVC 5 I have a controller action returning a gif image (therefore, not a view), like this:

```
[Route("Content/Images/GetThatGifImage.gif", Name = "Get the gif image")]

public ActionResult GetThatGif()
{
    // Some logic here...

    return new FilePathResult("TheGifImage.gif", "image/gif")); 
}
```

At the same time I've got a `_ViewStart.cshtml` doing one thing only: defining the layout for all the *views* in the application. Looks like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/TheLayout.cshtml";
}
```

`TheLayout.cshtml` contains code that requires a certain `ViewBag` property to be set, or else it correctly throws a `NullReferenceException`.

As far as I understand, the `_ViewStart.cshtml` should not in any way be involved if the controller returns another type than `ViewResult`. Right?

*But* quite often when visitors request `Content/Images/GetThatGifImage.gif` they are trapped by the exception and they get a `500 Internal Server Error`. Intriguingly, I haven't been able to reproduce the error myself, no matter how much I've tried. I can see the errors visitors get though, in the event log at the IIS server. It seems arbitrary, not happening on every request. The stack trace in the event log looks like this:

```
at ASP._Page_Views_Shared_TheLayout_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\ewp\Views\Shared\TheLayout.cshtml:line 81
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass3.<RenderPageCore>b__2(TextWriter writer)
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
at StackExchange.Profiling.Mvc.WrappedView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

At one point MVC starts `ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult` and then it's all down hill I guess to `ExecutePageHierarchy` that finally calls `ASP._Page_Views_Shared_TheLayout_cshtml.Execute()`.

One more fact: Once (!) I've noticed the exact same error with another controller not returning `ViewResult`. The stack trace in the event log is exactly the same. That controller returns `RedirectResult` after handling a POST request, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TakeCareOfFeedback()
{
    // Some logic here...

    return Redirect("/thanks-for-your-feedback");
}
```

---

### Finally, my questions summerized:

1. Why?
2. How to solve the problem (get the controller *not* to execute the `_ViewStart` file)?
3. Bonus: Why is it arbitrary?
4. Bonus: Why can't i reproduce it? Is there some reason other than the fact that it's arbitrary?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just a wild guess, but you have an Async call that is throwing an error, isn't caught and bringing down more than just itself.  Bringing down a different unrelated call that's hosted on the same thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug and yes, it was mine  :/

The action has a Custom Action Filter (`OnActionExecuting`) that reads the value from a cookie. It's embarrassing but I was missing to check if the cookie was null (cookie missing) before getting the value. So it throws a `NullReferenceException` when the cookie is missing. (I couldn't reproduce the error because in my environment the cookie was set.)

I still don't understand why `TheLayout.cshtml` (via `_ViewStart.cshtml`) gets involved though, giving me some misleading error info. Maybe it's because the first unhandled exception (my bug) somehow switches the result type to `ViewResult`. After all the action is about to show a kind of "view", namely the ASP.NET Yellow Screen of Death (YSOD). Maybe it has something to do with threads, like @Robert McKee suggests. It seems though that this only happens when `customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"`. If I switch to `customErrors mode="Off"` I get the correct error info. (I haven't explored this last bit further so I'm not sure of it.)